# Joomla 3 category blog template override

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

i am trying to implement a custom template override for category blog. So:

I have copied: templates/gk_startup/html/com_content/category/blog.php
and renamed to: templates/gk_startup/html/com_content/category/newsletter.php

I have created a category named: Newsletter and set Alternative Layout to "newsletter".

I have created a menu item of type: Articles/Category Blog and chosen category "Newsletter" to display.

However in the front end i can see that the blog.php "default" template for category blog is still used.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to accomplish what i was looking for by creating an alternate category blog layout as described here:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10374/how-to-create-a-category-blog-layout-with-all-articles-shown-in-full

So only by creating an override for the menu items also (specifying newsletter.xml in components/com_content/views/category/tmpl) i was able to use my newsletter override initially created in templates/gk_startup/html/com_content/category

Hope that helps in some cases